# htaccess dynamic query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, random

maybe this is a stupid question

i have current code below:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /image/modify.php?pic=$1 [QSA]
```

and i enter the url http://site.com/image/20121207/test.jpg&w=256

will display the resized image.the original url is:

http://site.com/image/modify.php?pic=20121207/test.jpg&w=256

but how can i change &w= to ?w= ?

the w= are random,perhaps someone will enter h= / r= ...etc

please give me some hint

Comment: I has add new answer ...
See if you confused  !

Answer (score 1):

The Apache rewriter is intelligent enough to process query parameters correctly. That's what the `QSA` is for, *"query string append"*. You can access `20121207/test.jpg?w=256` and it should be rewritten to `modify.php?pic=20121207/test.jpg&w=256` correctly.

Comment: but i enter ?w=256 it display the origin width image

Comment: That's a little too abstract. What `$_GET` parameters are you receiving in your script?

Comment: if(isset($_GET['pic']) && isset($_GET['w']) || isset($_GET['h']))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^?&]+)?(.*) /image/modify.php?pic=$1$2$3&$4 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

So easy :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?)(.*)$ /image/modify.php?pic=$1&$2 [QSA]
```

Hope it work ....

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]*)(?)(.*)$ /image/modify.php?pic=$1&$2 [QSA]
```

and enter the url:

```
http://site.com/image/20121207/test.jpg?w=256
```

i has try it, i think it will work ...
Good luck